# How can use Load balancing?

Tags: router, redundancy, load-balancing

if we do not configure HSRP or another protocol ,How data will flood if there is redundancy ?
please help me I need some explain about load balancing

Comment: how do you plan to achieve load balancing without these protocols ?

Comment: I've edited my  question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the data will flood (if it will) depends on the design.
If there it is a complete L2 network, then by the routes on the host it will forward the packets to the gateway. For that it needs the MAC of the gateway. If both gateways have the same IP, then the gateway that replies first for the ARP is selected. If they have different Ip then the gateway that is configured at the host will reply.

In the layer 3 network. it depends on the discretion of the routing protocol. If BGP is used than the admin has the flexibility of choosing the gateway.

Comment: thank you this is helpful , could you explain more about load balancing ?

Comment: @Ruby regardless the problem or the design requirements, it is always helpful for me to first clarify 3 things 1. What is the definition of load. That is what do you consider as load for your network. This can be number of packets , number of requests , number of bits/bytes, upload data , download data and the like. 2. What is the load balancing criteria . For example what will you consider as a balanced load ? Equal link utilization? Equal a server cpu utilization ? Load balanced between tenants , etc . 3. Finally how to you plan to achieve this criteria . Eg algorithms​, network design ,etc